# How to remove leading zero from double calculation?

Tags: swift

Consider the following, how do I remove the leading zero, and retain 3 decimals places? savePercentageDecimals returns 0.923, I would like just .923

```
    //Figure out Save Percentage
    let savePercentage = 12.0 / (1.0 + 12.0)
    let savePercentageDecimals = String(format: "%.3f",savePercentage)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if there is something for doing that. What about transforming the `Double` in a `String` and remove the first `Character` fi you assume that it is always the `0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NumberFormatter` is the class you want to use when displaying numbers as string. In your case, this will work :

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 0
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

let savePercentage = 12.0 / (1.0 + 12.0)
let savePercentageDecimals = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: savePercentage)) // .923
```

By using `minimumIntegerDigits` above, it doesn't remove leading significant numbers (>= 1):

```
let moreThan100Percent = (12.0 / (1.0 + 12.0)) + 1.0
let formattedWithDecimals = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: moreThan100Percent)) // 1.923
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, works great.  Thank You!